# What role does Marvin play in the heist in The Killing (1956)?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-killing-1956

In Stanley Kubrick's film The Killing, several men are assigned roles to ensure the successful heist of a racetrack.  As the heist unfolds we see Marvin appear in the track lobby visibly drunk.  (Marvin was the character who previously bet $5 on all the horses to win in the first racetrack scene)  His drunkenness concerns both the bartender and Sterling Hayden's character.

What was he supposed to do?  I get a sense it may have been something to do with the public-facing door used to gain entrance to the cash room, but I'm not sure what he could have done.

Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Marvin is the money man.

He provides the working capital for the job including the money to pay for the rifleman and the man starting the fight.

Johnny tells his girl...

> Take my pal Unger, for instance, the guy who owns this apartment.  **He's putting up the money to operate with** and he's letting me stay here.

As for his appearance during the robbery I suspect it's because he wasn't supposed to be there. He plays no part (other than logistical support) in the plan so one must assume that he was there just to make sure it went off. His drunkeness would therefore have been a concern.